# ASP.NET Cache always returns null

Tags: asp.net, sqlcachedependency

I am using `SQLCacheDependency` in my `ASP.NET` application with `Query Notifications`.
I followed [this article](http://keithelder.net/2009/01/20/sqldependency-and-sql-service-broker-permissions/) to set up my database with success.However whenever I am trying to store data in the `cache` object.It just does not hold value.It is always `null` .I am not getting any errors or exceptions.
Here is my code

**Global.asax**

```
void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Code that runs on application startup
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.
        Start(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["McdConn"].ToString());

    }

void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //  Code that runs on application shutdown
        System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDependency.
        Stop(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["McdConn"].ToString());
    }

public static class CacheManagement
{
    public static DataTable CreateCache(string cacheName, string tableName, string query)
    {
        DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
        try
        {
            string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["McdConn"].ToString();
            dtResult = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheName] as DataTable;

            if (dtResult == null)
            {
                dtResult = new DataTable();
                using (var cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                {
                    cn.Open();
                    var cmd = new SqlCommand(query, cn);
                    cmd.Notification = null;
                    cmd.NotificationAutoEnlist = true;
                    SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableNotifications(connectionString);
                    if (!SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.GetTablesEnabledForNotifications(connectionString).Contains(tableName))
                    {
                        SqlCacheDependencyAdmin.EnableTableForNotifications(connectionString,tableName);
                    }

                    var dependency = new SqlCacheDependency(cmd);
                    //SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                    //ad.Fill(dsResult);
                    SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                    dtResult.Load(reader);
                    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(cacheName, dtResult, dependency);

                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Exception_Log.ExceptionMethod("Web", "CacheManagement.cs", "CacheManagement", ex);
        }

        return dtResult = HttpContext.Current.Cache[cacheName] as DataTable;
    }

}
```

**Code Behind**

```
var dtCachedCategories = HttpContext.Current.Cache["tbl_CategoryMaster_Cached"] as DataTable;
if (dtCachedCategories == null)
{
 dtCachedCategories = CacheManagement.CreateCache("tbl_CategoryMaster_Cached","dbo.tbl_CategoryMaster_Languages", "Select * from dbo.tbl_CategoryMaster_Languages");

}
```

The above always returns `null`.

Can anyone help me in pointing out what could be missing?

Comment: could you provide more information on your problem tracking ? Is dtResult null when performing the insert ? Does it change anything when trying without query notifications ? with atomic type values ?

Comment: @jbl The `dtResult` is always null when retrieved from the cache.I think the Cache never holds `dtResult`.

Answer (score 4):

Well there's a lot you can do to debug your code and arrive at a conclusion. It seems like your cached item is getting removed too frequently.

1.) Use `CacheItemPriority.NotRemovable` to Cache.Insert() to  make sure ASP.NET doesn't removes
    your item whenever it feels so. use the `Insert()` method explained [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77.aspx). Check this [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitempriority.aspx) 
    article too.

2.) To find out the reason why your cached item is getting removed , log this removal action using 
    `CacheItemRemovedCallback`  delegate option of your `Cache.Insert()` method. Check this [Insert method 
     overload](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/05kd8d77.aspx) version and also this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.caching.cacheitemremovedcallback.aspx).

3.) Make sure your `dtresult` as well as your `reader` is not null. Check the lines:

`SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();`  &  `dtResult.Load(reader);` , together with your logs.

4.) Check your application Pool recycle time. This [link](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc753449%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) has everything related to App pool settings ( IIS 7 +).

5.) This link has a solution for App pool of IIS 6: http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/717129-c-asp-net-page-cache-getting-removed-too-soon

Also, try using [HttpRuntime.Cache](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpruntime.cache.aspx) method to see if it works.

```
System.Web.HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(cacheName, dtResult, dependency);
```